# CodeIgniter - Form Onload

Tags: javascript, php, codeigniter

How do I add onload javascript on code igniter forms?
Id like to achieve a code like this in code igniter

```
form onload="yourscript"
```

Codeigniter uses a `form_open()` command so I dunno how to add the onload script.

Comment: your answer already lies on the [user guide form helper - Adding Attributes](https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/helpers/form_helper.html)

Answer (score 1):

You can add attributes like that

```
$this->load->helper('form');
$attributes = array('onsubmit'=>'abc()');
echo form_open('url', $attributes);
```

form has no method of 'onload',so it makes no effect even if you set.